# Creating a webpage with JavaScript that updates automatically with new information

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a webpage using JavaScript and HTML that allows for users to insert new information as it becomes available to them and to preform calculations while keeping the given information the same. As well it needs to update the output given to them without requiring the entire page to refresh. A table style format would be preferable, but the easier to code the better. What would be the 'easiest' way to go about this?

Edit:
I apologize for not stating this earlier, I intend to just launch this page on my desktop by using a web browser it is not intended for a server application.

Edit2:
I would like to thank everyone for their help with my request! You have given me great pointers and i will definitely start with these. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you researched ajax? Many technologies can be used to achieve what you are asking, but we also need to know whether you have your own server and what language you are using server side etc to handle that type of content or whether it is a static site with technologies such as jekyll

Comment: I have taken bits and pieces before, but have never gone about learning it in depth. Do you recommend focusing on using it?

Comment: I would but there are many solutions to this particularly questions  such as static delivery as I mentioned after editing but a good place to start for ajax would be here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ but also as I said consider what delivery options you have such as static site generation technologies such as jekyll could be used if you wish to reduce delivery time etc but it would be easier to advise you if we know what technology you have or can afford to use for your site hosting etc, are you using php, jnode or asp.net etc or have you considered it?

Comment: you are describing most of the goals of a class of JavaScript applications typically referred to as Single Page Applications (or SPA, for short).  There are plenty different frameworks available for writing SPAs, for example, AngularJs, Meteor, Durandal, Backbone, etc....

Comment: My recommendation would be Angular, but the fact that I am making a recommendation actually means that this question is really off topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is AJAX. It's very useful, because you can do things as:

- Update a web page without reloading the page
- Request data from a server
- Receive data from a server
- Send data to a server

You can find some good JavaScript tutorials:

- [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/index.htm)
- [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp)
- [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](http://mdn.io/ajax)
- [LearnToProgram](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqRiDlm-SnY)

or a jQuery one [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).